# How to get parent and children elements by Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I get the children elements of parent elements as

```
const a = await page.$$('a');

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
constant link = // How to get HREF of a[i]?
const photo = await a[i].$eval('img', el => el.getAttribute('src'));
console.log(link);
console.log(photo);
}
```

but how can I get the attributes of the parent since `a[i]` is a puppeteer handle rather than DOM element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `evaluate` function. Puppeteer will know how to use the handle.

```js
const href= await page.evaluate(el => el.href, a[i])
```